# FG Frequency output

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, frequency

I have bought the [Brushless DC-Flat Motors Series 2610](https://www.faulhaber.com/en/products/series/2610b-sc/) and Pin number 6 is called FG which is defined as frequency output. I have plugged this pin into the Arduino in A0 and I have tried displaying the outputs. The outputs is either 0 or 1023 and I am not sure how I can convert this to angular speed or RPM. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Without looking at the motor, I'm pretty sure, that this is not an analog output. Almost certainly it is a digital pulse output. So it will output a specific number of pulses per revolution of the motor (Thus you can get the RPM by counting the pulses per time interval). You get 0 and 1023, because you are just reading the HIGH and LOW signal parts of the pulsed signal.

Comment: That will be a hall effect output giving you a square wave, the frequency equal to (or proportional to) the RPM.

Comment: in the manual it says "6 lines per revolution" does this mean that I need to observe 6 ones in a row for a revolution to be considered? or is a pulse a 0 followed by a 1 then a 0. Sorry if I'm asking basic questions